# Can I repick ideological tenets after forced to switch to different ideology

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-brave-new-world

Lets assume I was forced to change my ideology with several applied tenets to another ideology. Will I have the same number to tenets to reapply or should I start from the scratch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you switch ideologies (either voluntarily or involuntarily), you'll be able to re-pick a number of tenets in the new ideology equal to the number of tenets you had in your old ideology.

The only caveat to this that I've seen is that you'll lose the "early adopter" tenets - the bonus ones you get if you were one of the first two civs to pick an ideology.